# How can I learn to build my own bootloader for an embedded system?

Tags: embedded

Does anyone know of a good learning resource for building your own bootloader for an embedded system? From reading various textbooks, I have a good overview of what a bootloader is supposed to do, and some textbooks include snippets of assembler to show how the bootloader should be built.

However, when I search for resources/tutorials that describe how to build a bootloader, everything I've found so far is either too advanced, (assuming a knowledge of certain preliminaries and are thus hard to follow), or, they are dealing with creating a bootloader for a pc or an emulator. Ideally I'm looking for a single resource/book, that covers preliminaries, and walks me through the process. I'm happy to purchase a particular chip, and relevant cables, if the tutorial/textbook requires that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term bootloader is quite broad, so does your quest have roots in a few dozen lines of code with a serial bootloader or are you interested in a linux type full blown operating system (uboot) that has gobs of features and drivers and stacks?

If you dont already know that answer or dont know what I am talking about you need to figure that out, I would start small...even if you desire the huge monster operating system solution, you should start with bare metal (which is what a bootloader is, a bare metal program) chip comes out of reset, your code runs first, blinks an led.  Then control the rate of the blinking led, then if you have a push button read the push button and make it change the led (demonstrating input and output).  Then find and use a timer to blink the led if you didnt already (use polling first please, interrupts later).  Now you can do clock math and have an idea how the chips clock tree is so use that to get a uart up, tx only first, then rx/tx echo what your receive.  THEN you are ready to talk about your first bootloader, which should involve some serial protocol (invent your own or use xmodem or something) that actually "boots" and then lets you "load" other programs after booting.

You can do all of this (well virtual leds in some other form) using simulators, and that may not be a bad idea since the hard part of bare metal is first off controlling the assembler compiler and linker to make a binary that actually boots up and runs.  Then piles of sub $10 and sub $20 boards that you can learn to write a bootloader for (msp430 launchpads, the other launchpads, stm32f0 and f4 discovery boards, the raspberry pi, probably not the beagles avoid those for now, oh and a myriad of avr based boards, avoid x86 start with microcontrollers, arm, avr, msp430).

Comment: Yes I want to start very small to begin with. So that's useful to know that I could probably start with an emulator and graduate to raspberry pi.

Comment: then you will probably eventually find my raspberry pi xmodem bootloader, and you can improve on it since it was a 30 minute project.  Whether it is good, bad, or otherwise, just understanding it is valuable knowledge. (why did I put the program in ram where I did, understand the uart init, understand the uart tx and rx routines, then of course the xmodem stuff and then how it jumps to the loaded program).